# Feign client error: feign.RetryableException: PKIX path validation failed: Path does not chain with any of the trust anchors

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-feign, feign, openfeign

I keep getting an error when I use feign to call another service. the error is

> {"timestamp":"2023-06-16 15:29:02.498","level":"ERROR","thread":"https-jsse-nio-1363-exec-6","mdc":{"urlPath":"/v1/elig-file-builder/spec/1210/sponsor","requestId":"1686929342334352869DWBBLUYAXA"},"logger":"com.collectivehealth.file.builder.exceptions.RestErrorHandlerAdvice","message":"encountered internal server exception","context":"default","exception":"com.collectivehealth.file.builder.exceptions.NoSuchSponsorException: Error in calling bizcore to get the sponsor data for sponsor codes [[]] \n\tat com.collectivehealth.file.builder.service.SponsorService.loadSponsors(SponsorService.java:79)\n\tat com.collectivehealth.file.builder.service.SpecService.getSpecSponsors(SpecService.java:240)\n\tat com.collectivehealth.file.builder.service.SpecService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$ee21a753.invoke()\n\tat org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy.invokeMethod(CglibAopProxy.java:386)\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy.access$000(CglibAopProxy.java:85)\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:704)\n\tat com.collectivehealth.file.builder.service.SpecService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f3fe9ada.getSpecSponsors()\n\tat com.collectivehealth.file.builder.resources.SpecResource.getSpecSponsors(SpecResource.java:122)\n\tat com.collectivehealth.file.builder.resources.SpecResource$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$3591ea40.invoke()\n\tat org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:793)\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763)\n\tat org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:89)\n\tat com.collectivehealth.authz.processors.AuthorizationAnnotationProcessor.doAuthorizeCheck(AuthorizationAnnotationProcessor.java:41)\n\tat com.collectivehealth.authz.processors.FeignAwareAuthorizationAnnotationProcessor.doAuthorizeCheck(FeignAwareAuthorizationAnnotationProcessor.java:27)\n\tat jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor103.invoke(Unknown Source)\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)\n\tat org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:634)\n\tat org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:624)\n\tat org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:72)\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:175)\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763)\n\tat org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763)\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:708)\n\tat com.collectivehealth.file.builder.resources.SpecResource$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$548f34a9.getSpecSponsors()\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1070)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\n\tat com.collectivehealth.base.core.filters.RequestTaggingFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestTaggingFilter.java:43)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\n\tat net.rakugakibox.spring.boot.logback.access.LogbackAccessSecurityAttributesSaveFilter.doFilter(LogbackAccessSecurityAttributesSaveFilter.java:28)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\n\tat com.collectivehealth.base.core.filters.HttpRequestCountTemplatedFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpRequestCountTemplatedFilter.java:49)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\n\tat com.collectivehealth.base.core.filters.HttpResponseLatencyTemplatedFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpResponseLatencyTemplatedFilter.java:49)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:327)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:81)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:122)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:116)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:126)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:81)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:109)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:149)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:166)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)\n\tat com.collectivehealth.security.authentication.filters.CHAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(CHAuthenticationFilter.java:90)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:112)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:82)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:211)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:183)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:354)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\n\tat org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:96)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)\n\tat net.rakugakibox.spring.boot.logback.access.tomcat.LogbackAccessTomcatValve.invoke(LogbackAccessTomcatValve.java:91)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:769)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360)\n\tat org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399)\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:890)\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1789)\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)\nCaused by: feign.RetryableException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Path does not chain with any of the trust anchors executing GET https://bizcore:1363/v1/sponsor/sponsor_codes/\n\tat feign.FeignException.errorExecuting(FeignException.java:268)\n\tat feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.executeAndDecode(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:129)\n\tat feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.invoke(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:89)\n\tat feign.ReflectiveFeign$FeignInvocationHandler.invoke(ReflectiveFeign.java:100)\n\tat jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy213.getSponsorsBySponsorCodesFromBizcore(Unknown Source)\n\tat com.collectivehealth.file.builder.clients.BizcoreClient.getSponsorsBySponsorCodes(BizcoreClient.java:26)\n\tat com.collectivehealth.file.builder.service.SponsorService.loadSponsors(SponsorService.java:63)\n\t... 144 common frames omitted\nCaused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Path does not chain with any of the trust anchors\n\tat java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131)\n\tat java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:371)\n\tat java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:314)\n\tat java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:309)\n\tat java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:654)\n\tat java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.onCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:473)\n\tat java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:369)\n\tat java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:396)\n\tat java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:480)\n\tat java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:458)\n\tat java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:201)\n\tat java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:172)\n\tat java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1505)\n\tat java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1420)\n\tat java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:455)\n\tat java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:426)\n\tat okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.kt:379)\n\tat okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.establishProtocol(RealConnection.kt:337)\n\tat okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.kt:209)\n\tat okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findConnection(ExchangeFinder.kt:226)\n\tat okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findHealthyConnection(ExchangeFinder.kt:106)\n\tat okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.find(ExchangeFinder.kt:74)\n\tat okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.initExchange$okhttp(RealCall.kt:255)\n\tat okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.kt:32)\n\tat okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)\n\tat okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.kt:95)\n\tat okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)\n\tat okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.kt:83)\n\tat okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)\n\tat okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.kt:76)\n\tat okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)\n\tat okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain$okhttp(RealCall.kt:201)\n\tat okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.execute(RealCall.kt:154)\n\tat feign.okhttp.OkHttpClient.execute(OkHttpClient.java:172)\n\tat feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.executeAndDecode(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:119)\n\t... 149 common frames omitted\nCaused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Path does not chain with any of the trust anchors\n\tat java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doValidate(PKIXValidator.java:369)\n\tat java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:275)\n\tat java.base/sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:264)\n\tat java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:231)\n\tat java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:132)\n\tat java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:638)\n\t... 179 common frames omitted\nCaused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Path does not chain with any of the trust anchors\n\tat java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXCertPathValidator.java:157)\n\tat java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.engineValidate(PKIXCertPathValidator.java:83)\n\tat java.base/java.security.cert.CertPathValidator.validate(CertPathValidator.java:309)\n\tat java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doValidate(PKIXValidator.java:364)\n\t... 184 common frames omitted\n","module":"app"}{"timestamp":"2023-06-16 15:29:02.501","level":"WARN","thread":"sentry-pool-1-thread-1","mdc":{"urlPath":"/v1/elig-file-builder/spec/1210/sponsor","requestId":"1686929342334352869DWBBLUYAXA"},"logger":"io.sentry.connection.AbstractConnection.lockdown","message":"Initiated a temporary lockdown because of exception: An exception occurred while submitting the event to the Sentry server.","context":"default","module":"app"}

my pom.xml has mockwebserver and feign-okhtt dependencies which I think It causes a conflict

pom.xml

```
<parent>
    <artifactId>spring-base-app-parent</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.collectivehealth</groupId>
    <version>4.1.2</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <jackson-datatype-jsr310.version>2.14.1</jackson-datatype-jsr310.version>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
    <spring-cloud.version>2021.0.4</spring-cloud.version>
    <spring-cloud-aws.version>2.2.6.RELEASE</spring-cloud-aws.version>
    <okhttp-version>4.11.0</okhttp-version>
    <mockwebserver-version>4.11.0</mockwebserver-version>
</properties>

<artifactId>elig-file-builder</artifactId>
<version>1.24.0</version>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.collectivehealth</groupId>
        <artifactId>ch-spring-starter-standard</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-aws</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-cloud-aws.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson-datatype-jsr310.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
        <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
        <version>5.7.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
        <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
        <version>${okhttp-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockwebserver</artifactId>
        <version>${mockwebserver-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.openfeign</groupId>
        <artifactId>feign-okhttp</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-text</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <linkXRef>false</linkXRef>
                <rulesets>
                    <ruleset>/pmd-rules.xml</ruleset>
                </rulesets>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-failsafe-plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <classpathDependencyExcludes>
                    <classpathDependencyExclude>org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-aws-autoconfigure</classpathDependencyExclude>
                </classpathDependencyExcludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>check</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <configLocation>default-ch-checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
                        <sourceDirectories>
                            <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
                        </sourceDirectories>
                        <excludes>**/generated-*/**/*</excludes>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.collectivehealth.corelibs</groupId>
                    <artifactId>static-analysis</artifactId>
                    <version>2.4.0</version>
                    <scope>compile</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.puppycrawl.tools</groupId>
                    <artifactId>checkstyle</artifactId>
                    <version>10.3.4</version>
                    <scope>compile</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <configuration>
                <configLocation>default-ch-checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
                <sourceDirectories>
                    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
                </sourceDirectories>
                <excludes>**/generated-*/**/*</excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
```

the feign client class is

```
@Component @Slf4j @AllArgsConstructor public class BizcoreClient {
private final BizcoreFeign bizcoreFeign;
private final AuthenticationService authenticationService;

public String getSponsorsBySponsorCodes(List<String> sponsorCodes) {
    String token = authenticationService.getRequestToken();
    if (StringUtils.isEmpty(token)) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(" unable to hit bizcore endpoint because the token is empty");
    }
    log.info("token is " + token);
    String sCodes = sponsorCodes.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(","));
    return bizcoreFeign.getSponsorsBySponsorCodesFromBizcore(sCodes, token);
}}
```

the class that use feign

```
   @Component @Slf4j @AllArgsConstructor public class BizcoreClient {
private final BizcoreFeign bizcoreFeign;
private final AuthenticationService authenticationService;

public String getSponsorsBySponsorCodes(List<String> sponsorCodes) {
    String token = authenticationService.getRequestToken();
    if (StringUtils.isEmpty(token)) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(" unable to hit bizcore endpoint because the token is empty");
    }
    log.info("token is " + token);
    String sCodes = sponsorCodes.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(","));
    return bizcoreFeign.getSponsorsBySponsorCodesFromBizcore(sCodes, token);
}
```

}

the feign configuration class

```
public class FeignClientConfiguration {

@Bean
Encoder feignFormEncoder(ObjectFactory<HttpMessageConverters> converters) {
    return new SpringFormEncoder(new SpringEncoder(converters));
}

@Bean
public OkHttpClient client() {
    return new OkHttpClient();
}}
```

any idea how to resolve this error?

Comment: Check here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/12524960/6707702